# How to update cells in a Container View

Tags: ios, objective-c, container-view

I have my *storyboard* set up like this:

1. A view defined as a custom class, let's call it `V1ViewController`
2. This view has a view container
3. The view container has a `UITableViewController` with a set of static cells
4. The cells are of style "Left Detail"

I'm trying to access the text box in the Left Detail from the code in `V1ViewController`, but can't seem to figure out how to traverse that hierarchy. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have an IBOutlet for your container VC?

Comment: Yes I can add one in the V1ViewController.

Comment: Then access the table view from that reference.

Comment: My problem is I don't understand how to do that. Logically it seems I should be able to do something like this...self.containeroutlet.tableviewname.cellname

Comment: Thanks for all the responses, I'll try to get this working this weekend and accept an answer once I do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the proper way to get a reference to your child view controller:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
   if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString: @"childViewControllerSegue"]) {
       ChildViewController *myChildViewController = (ChildViewController *) [segue destinationViewController];
       //With myChildViewController you can access your child view controller for example:
       [myChildViewController.myTableView reloadData];   
   }
}
```

Keep in mind that because this is a Container view this method will be called upon load of your `ViewController`. Therefore it would be a good idea to save `myChildViewController` as a property or an instance variable for later use.

Answer (score 2):

I am  going to disagree with most of the other responders. I strongly advise against trying to manipulate the child view controller's table view (or any of it's view contents.)

You should treat a view controller's view hierarchy as private.

Instead, I would save a pointer to the child view controller in your prepareForSegue method (as shown in sha's post).

Make your child view controller a custom subclass of UITableViewController with methods that let you specify new content for the left views of your static cells.

Then, in the parent view controller, when you want to change something in the table view, use the saved pointer to the custom table view controller (myChildViewController) to invoke methods that make the desired changes for you. It's pretty easy.

I have a sample app on github that illustrates using container views and static table views. I wanted my design to be as general-purpose as possible, so I defined protocols for both child-to-parent and parent-to-child communications.

Check out this demo of [**using static table views in a container view**](https://github.com/DuncanMC/test).

Answer (score 0):

Move in trash your's containter view with tableviewcontroller. Use instead `UITableView`. You can easily create `IBOutlet` on it. Or you can even subclass yours `V1ViewController` from `UITableViewController` (depends on what should be displayed on the screen). And then implement in yours `V1ViewController` `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` required methods.